# verify ios developer account on backend

Tags: ios, security

I have an application (App1), which will open another application (App2) with a secure token, using openURL method (such as App2://[secureToken]). App1 and App2 are on seperate developer accounts so using entitlement & keychain access groups is not an option for data sharing here, which I would normally do.

Any app can register any url scheme according to Apple documentation. iOS will randomly select  which application will be opened. So there is a risk that a malware may register App2://. App1 will open that malware with secure token instead of App2.

I need a way to make sure that secure token can be used by only App2, on the backend services. I have access to both client and backend source codes.

I have thought of distributing App2 with a hardcoded key and add this to keychain and generate some sort of hash using that information. But I believe hardcoding a key is not strong enough for this scenario, considering secure token contains highly critical information. (hardcoded keys can easily be compromised see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52584/why-can-we-still-crack-snapchat-photos-in-12-lines-of-ruby)

Is there a way to verify the developer account of App2 on the backend? I would prefer this as a solution but any alternatives, will be also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest thing I found to this is receipts. (free apps also has receipts) The problem is there is nothing to identify a unique device in the receipt, so it is still spoofable. There are some useful information like original purchase date for fraud detection, but its not very useful on its own.

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1)

Facebook lists this vulnerability as "Stealing of URL schemes" (https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/securely-developing-on-mobile/10151408888270766)

and recommends

"To mitigate spoofing of callers' URL schemes, the Facebook SDK also lets callers to the main app choose an encryption key for their response."

To avoid hardcoding enryption key, I guess I will do something like this.

If App2 did not authenticate before, App1 will not create a secure token. When App2 first authenticates, a key will be generated serverside and delivered to App2. It will be stored in keychain.

The next time App1 invokes App2, App1 will query that key from server and use this information to encypt secure token.